# Link to partial view inside another partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a main global layoutfile and in one of my menu items I link to a service catalog that has it's own sidemenu generated from Model. Here's a simplified version of that view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Service>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="list-group">
                <ul class="service-menu-list">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#@item.Id" class="service-menu-link service-menu-item" id="serviceItem-@item.Id">
                                <i class="service-menu-list-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                <span class="service-menu-list-text">&nbsp;@item.Name</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ServicesMainContainer" class="col-xs-8">
            @Html.Partial("_ServicesStart")
        </div>
```

This sidemenu will generate a partialview to the right depending on which item you've clicked in the menu. I manage this with an jquery ajax call that looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".service-menu-link", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var itemID = $(this).attr("id");
    var container = $("#ServicesMainContainer");
    var href = {
        Href: $(this).attr("href")
    }
    removeActiveCLass();
    addActiveClass(itemID);

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("_ShowService")",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(href),
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR: " + errorThrown.text());
        },
        success: function(result) {
            container.html(result).show();

        }
    });
});
```

Here's also my Controllers for the main Service page:

```
public ActionResult Services()
    {
        var db = new IdentityDb();
        var serviceList = db.Services.ToList();
        return View("Services", serviceList);
    }
```

...And my partial view:

```
public ActionResult _ShowService(string href)
        {
            if (href == "#home")
            {
                return PartialView("_ServicesStart");
            }
            else
            {
                var db = new IdentityDb();
                var stringId = href.Substring(href.IndexOf("#") + 1);
                var id = Convert.ToInt32(stringId);

                var service = db.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

                return PartialView("_ShowService", service);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I want to link to specific Services from my index page, meaning that I want to load the Services page with the menu but with the specific service already visible. 
If I link to my Services action, I come to the starting area of the Service catalog, and I can't link to my _ShowService Partial view because it will just show the partial view without any css, layout and Servicecatalog menu.

Any ideas on how I would link to that partial view but not lose the main layout?